# Export data file from tablet Archos to PC or SDcard, USB key

Tags: android, file-io, xamarin.android, android-sdcard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Transfer data from Tablet to PC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11359214/transfer-data-from-tablet-to-pc)

I am writing an application for the Archos tablet. I load a file at at the same time as with the .apk file (like assets). I can read from this file from my application, but I can not write to it.

I also do not know how read it on the PC for using the written data (in fact, export, file, from tablet to PC). Or another way, to export data from tablet, to the PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just detail....

I creat folder and MyTextFile.txt.
I can use this file but file is creat at local: /sdcard/MyFolder.
I can read and write this file, but it isn't in physical SDcard.
I don't know, how write on SDcard or USB key (extern, in port of my Archos101 tablet).

It is good think, that I can now,  export datas from tablet to PC ....
But,only with USB cable, it's was better, if I can stock this file with extern support.

Do you Know how think '' thru path '' of SDcard and USB ?Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory gets me the intern path (local: /sdcard/MyFolder), and not SD card, or USB key path. 
Thank you.

Serge.

Comment: I prefere, that you close another topic and open this.

Answer (score 0):

Writing to Assets cannot be done on Android, only reading from Assets is possible. Hence you have to save your file to the SD card or a USB key.

Writing to one of these can be achieved in the following manner:

```
var folder = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory + Java.IO.File.Separator + "MyFolder";

try
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(folder))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);

    folder = folder + Java.IO.File.Separator;

    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(folder + "MyTextFile.txt"))
    {
        sw.WriteLine("Testing");
    }

    //This saves Bitmap
    using (var fs = new FileStream(folder + "MyImageFile.png", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
    {
            _myBitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, fs);
    } 
}
catch
{
    //handle the exception
}
```

The `Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory` gets you the path to the SD card or the USB key.

Comment: I thaks very well Cheesebaron for help me.

Comment: I thanks very well Cheesebaron, to help me.

Comment: Its exatly that I want, thank, Cheesebaron....